# Identifying first sort column in a formula

Tags: excel

If I have a spreadsheet, is there anyway for me to identify the first sort column (either through a simple sort, or a custom sort) for use in a a formula?

For instance, lets say the user sorts on column B, then is there anyway to do something like

```
=sort_col(1)
```

Which would equal B when sorting on B, C when sorting on C, etc.?

Comment: " anyway for me to identify the first sort column .." So you mean your list has been sorted before you get it.. ? Or you want to sort a column using a formula?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think such a thing exists.
The only thing you can do is verifying whether or not a column is sorted, which you can achieve using a helper column.

Imagine you want to check if column "A" is ordered. You can use a helper column (let's say column "B", starting with the value `TRUE` and all the rest having the formula `=(A2>=A1)`, dragging this formula up to the end of the column.
At the end (imagine you have 10 entries), you put in B11 the formula `=AND(B1:B10)`. If this is `TRUE` then column "A" is sorted.

Do this for all the columns you want to verify and you'll know which are sorted.